# How to rearrange query result in excel format using different queries

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, pivot-table, union-all

I have below 2 queries which i have joined them using `UNION ALL`. For `count(distinct ID)` column and for `count(distinct src_id)` column the query result should be in different column. For  `count(distinct id)` the alias will be IDl and for `count(distinct SRC_ID)` the alias will be `VOL`.  Also my query result should look like this as mentioned in excel . I want this result in this format because i want to paste the query result in excel and it will reduce my manual work if i format it in query itself. I tried previously directly to use PLSQL Procedure and get the result in excel but it looks very complex. I am getting error message as missing right parenthesis where i have used `UNION ALL`

```
Select * from (
SELECT ID,src_id               
     FROM ckt_GRP
          )
UNION ALL
select  ID,src_id from TEST_GRP
)
pivot(count(distinct id) for tbl in('IDl' IDl))  
pivot(count(distinct src_id) for tb2 in('VOL' VOL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go into specifics for your query however please check the below logic to create separate columns if that is what you wanted...

```
Select ID, Type, IDH, DMVOL from
( Select ID, Type, count(distinct HORDER.H_ORDER_BK) IDH, 0 DMVOL from Table_A
  Union All
  Select ID, Type, 0 IDH, count(distinct ordmast_srcid) DMVOL from Table_B )
```

P.S : I am not able to open the image link.

Edit: [try this]

```
Select sys_db_name,entity_id,ORD_DEL_DT,SUM(IDH) IDH, Sum(DM_VOL) DM_VOL from (
SELECT 'IDH' tb1,LDELIVERYORDER.sys_db_name sys_db_name,
          SORDERMAIN.ENTITY_ID ENTITY_ID,
          TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (ORD_DEL_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')) ORD_DEL_DT,
          count(distinct HORDER.H_ORDER_BK) IDH,
          0 DM_VOL
     FROM INT_CDW_DV.L_DELIVERY_ORDER LDELIVERYORDER
          INNER JOIN
          INT_CDW_DV.H_ORDER HORDER
             ON     HORDER.H_ORDER_ID = LDELIVERYORDER.H_ORDER_ID
                AND HORDER.SYS_DB_NAME = LDELIVERYORDER.SYS_DB_NAME
                AND HORDER.SYS_DB_NAME in ('AS')
          INNER JOIN
          (SELECT S_ORDER_MAIN.ENTITY_ID,
                  S_ORDER_MAIN.H_ORDER_ID,
                  S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME
             FROM INT_CDW_DV.S_ORDER_MAIN
                  INNER JOIN
                  (  SELECT S_ORDER_MAIN.H_ORDER_ID,
                            S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME,
                            MAX (S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS)
                               AS SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS
                       FROM INT_CDW_DV.S_ORDER_MAIN
                      WHERE S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME  in ('AS')
                   GROUP BY S_ORDER_MAIN.H_ORDER_ID, S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME) b
                     ON     S_ORDER_MAIN.H_ORDER_ID = b.H_ORDER_ID
                        AND S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS =
                               b.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS
                        AND S_ORDER_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME = b.SYS_DB_NAME) SORDERMAIN
             ON     HORDER.H_ORDER_ID = SORDERMAIN.H_ORDER_ID
                AND HORDER.SYS_DB_NAME = SORDERMAIN.SYS_DB_NAME
          INNER JOIN
          (SELECT S_DELIVERY_MAIN.ORD_DEL_DT,
                  S_DELIVERY_MAIN.H_DELIV_ID,
                  S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME
             FROM INT_CDW_DV.S_DELIVERY_MAIN
                  INNER JOIN
                  (  SELECT S_DELIVERY_MAIN.H_DELIV_ID,
                            S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME,
                            MAX (S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS)
                               AS SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS
                       FROM INT_CDW_DV.S_DELIVERY_MAIN
                      WHERE 
                      S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME in ('AS')
                   GROUP BY S_DELIVERY_MAIN.H_DELIV_ID,
                            S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME) b
                     ON     S_DELIVERY_MAIN.H_DELIV_ID = b.H_DELIV_ID
                        AND S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS =
                               b.SYS_VALID_FROM_DTS
                        AND S_DELIVERY_MAIN.SYS_DB_NAME = b.SYS_DB_NAME) SDELIVERYMAIN
             ON     LDELIVERYORDER.H_DELIV_ID = SDELIVERYMAIN.H_DELIV_ID
                AND LDELIVERYORDER.SYS_DB_NAME = SDELIVERYMAIN.SYS_DB_NAME
    WHERE ORD_DEL_DT between to_date ('20170717', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date ('20170723', 'YYYYMMDD')
    and LDELIVERYORDER.sys_db_name in ('AS') and SORDERMAIN.ENTITY_ID = 26
          group by LDELIVERYORDER.sys_db_name,
          SORDERMAIN.ENTITY_ID,
          TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (ORD_DEL_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'))
          order by LDELIVERYORDER.sys_db_name,
          SORDERMAIN.ENTITY_ID,
          TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (ORD_DEL_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'))
UNION ALL
select  'DMVOL' tb2,sys_db_name,entity_id,shipping_dayid ORD_DEL_DT, 0 IDH, count(distinct ordmast_srcid) DM_VOL
from int_pub_edw.dm_valid_order_line
where shipping_dayid between 20170717 and 20170723
and sys_db_name = 'AS'
and entity_id = 26
and valid_order=1
group by sys_db_name,entity_id,shipping_dayid
) group by sys_db_name,entity_id,ORD_DEL_DT
```

Comment: I have tried and updated my answer in question but i am getting error as missing right paranthesis in UNION ALL line and also i have updated my answer and added Pivot condition at bottom but not sure whether its correct

Comment: It gives the same error as missing parenthesis at UNION ALL